# Where I can Find The CrmJobEditor Source Code?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

Does anyone know where I can find the source code of the CrmJobEditor. It is not available in CodePlex anymore at this link:
https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=crmjobeditor

Only some xaml files are there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After codeplex retirement, some people moved the repository to github. Sean from MS PFE team created [this github repo](https://github.com/seanmcne/DynamicsCRMOnPremJobEditor) for the CRM job editor.